# Install C dynamic libraries locally

Tags: c, project, portability, apt, lib

I want to install a library (all .so files in my case) in my C project folder in order to make it portable.

The wanted result is a project that, when you download it, allows you to compile it without needing to install something with "apt", "dpkg", etc...

I managed to copy .so files from `/usr/lib/...` in my project folder and link it with `-Lmylibfolder` "gcc" option. (I did the same for headers with `-Imyincludefolder`).

But that, this is for libraries I need directly, and I think there are sub-dependencies I need to copy too. Moreover my method consist in copying files manually and this is not very "clean".

Is there a good way to do what I want?

Comment: The libraries installed on your machine were compiled for your CPU and operating system. Including them in your project folder (assuming that you even have the right to distribute them) will make your project less portable, not more portable. On the other hand, if you're only intending to distribute your project to people who have the same CPU and OS that you do, why not just compile and link your program and distribute the binary?

Comment: It's a university project, I have to use OpenGL and my program must compile on the university computers. The problem is that there is only freeglut installed and I need to use glfw in order to capture the mouse. I don't intend to distribute it. I don't have the permission to install something but my teacher said it's ok to use glfw if I can compile on their computers